# How to use MvxCachingFragmentActivity?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to work with navigation with only Fragments, for tombestoning, saving total navigation stack and paramaters, etc. (working with Xamarin.Android and MVVMCross)

I think  MvxCachingFragmentActivity contains all needed parts.

But I can't seem to get it to work and I can't find any example project that works with FullFragging. Closest thing is the example from Cheesebaron https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MvxFragmentsAndHamburger , after removing some comments to load the ViewModels it worked but not for FullFragging and total NavigationStack recovery after activity has been destroyed.

Anyone any suggestions where to start? or and example that uses navigation with FullFragging and of course recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example that is a work in progress: https://github.com/steffkelsey/Xamarin_MvvmCross_MaterialDesign

Comment: A new example that handles this is available here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples